# Application bounces and never launches and it is Catalina fault. How to make it launch?

Tags: applications, catalina, crash, performance

Forgive me for this little rant.

Catalina is Apple's Windows Vista.

Said that, I have 10 to 20 little glitches, hangs and crashes with Catalina per day.

Beyond crashing every time I shutdown, one of the most annoying is an application that hangs and cannot be started after that, unless you do a full macOS restart.

After decades of experience, my guess is that the problem is the half-assed APFS, specially running on a spinning disk, like in my computer.

Imagine I am running, for example Filezilla. I try to download a file from my FTP server and suddenly, here we go... spinning ball of death.

After "hours" of that, I kill Filezilla (cmd-alt-esc).

Trying to launch Filezilla again will not work. The app will bounce 100 times and not launch.

All other apps work fine, except for the one hanged that was killed.

Finder, for example, has a similar problem. Hangs copying files. The solution: you restart Finder and the problem is gone.

My question is: what I have to kill from memory to make the problematic app run again? It must be something hanged in memory that is preventing that app from running.

Restarting the computer is rubbish. What can I do from terminal to solve questions like that?

[This is what shows](https://cl1p.net/glith) on terminal when I type `ps -ax`, after killing Filezilla. Note, killing PID 3106 from that listing makes no difference.

Comment: APFS wasn’t meant for spinning drives.  How did you install Catalina?

Comment: What are you talking about? I installed it from Apple when the final releases was released. Catalina converted my HFS+ main disk into APFS without asking.

Comment: Did you upgrade or do a clean install?

Comment: upgraded from mojave. But did a clean install after that due to a lot of problems in Catalina.

Comment: You really should return to High Sierra, where you can install onto an HFS volume.  The problem there is going to be that security updates for it are going to end soon.